# Laplace Transform to solve ODE

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta, boundary-value-problem, integral-transforms

I'm trying to solve the BVP $f''(x)=\delta(x-a)$ where $0<a<1$ and $f(0)=f(1)=1$ but I'm really not sure where to start. I tried taking the Laplace Transform of the equation, to get (after applying $f(0)=0$):

$p^2\bar{f}(p)-f'(0)=e^{-ap}$

But I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to somehow eliminate the $f'(0)$ term, and I'm sure I have to do this via the other condition $f(1)=0$, but not sure how to apply it. Then I'd invert $\bar{f}(p)$.

Some ideas: Maybe a change of variables $x\to 1-x$? and appeal to symmetry of delta function. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You have to be careful: The Laplace transform of $u''(t)$ is $$L(u''(t))(s) = s\cdot L(u'(t))(s)-u'(0),$$ so in terms of just $u$ you get  $$L(u''(t))(s)=s\cdot(s\cdot L(u(t))(s)-u'(0))-u(0)$$

Comment: That's not quite right. I think you have your u and u' mixed up

Comment: Because I can't edit my comment (you are right, I mixed up $u(0)$ and $u'(0)$ there): One has
$$L(u''(t))(s) = s( sL(u(t))(s)-u(0))-u'(0),$$

so when writing $\hat u := L(u(t))$, $u_0 := u(0)$, $u_0':= u'(0)$, your ODE becomes

$$s^2 \hat u(s) - su_0-u'_0 = \frac{e^{-a s}}{s},$$
which is of course equivalent to 
$$\hat u(s) = \frac{s^2 u_0 + su_0' + e^{-as}}{s^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Do a first of integration "by hand":

$$f'(t)=Y(t-a)+k$$

where $Y$ is Heaviside function, and $k$ a constant to be obtained later (by Initial Conditions).

Then only, apply Laplace Transform :

$$sF(s)-\underbrace{f(0)}_1=\frac{e^{-sa}}{s}+ks$$

$$F(s)=\dfrac{e^{-sa}}{s^2}+\dfrac{1}{s}+k$$

Can you proceed from here ?

Comment: I got a different RHS after applying LT. Isn't the Laplace transform of Heaviside $H(x-a)$ equal to $e^{-ap}$?

Comment: You are right. I was distracted !

Comment: Fixed now......

Comment: Applying directly Laplace Transform to the second order equation, you have a $f'(0)$ to which you cannot give  at once a value, but only at the very end.

Comment: Actually, even I'm distracted since Laplace Transform of $H(x-a)$ is not $e^{-ap}$ but actually $\frac{e^{-ap}}{p}$

Comment: I had forgotten to consult Laplace Transform tables ... Not a good habit